# How to Recursively Read Multiple Files from a Directory?

Tags: file-io, functional-programming, scheme, racket

Racket/Scheme Question

Background:
I have 1 master-directory, with 12 sub-directories and 40+ total files with the extension: .faa

Goal: 
- recursively read all files in sub-directories with the extension .faa 
- for each read-char equal to #> , add1 and return total number of #> across all files with the matching extension .faa

```
(define scrape-directory
  (lambda (path)
    (for ([f (in-directory path)] #:when (regexp-match? "\\.faa$" f))
      < HELP HERE > ))
```

Comment: Is there a more specific part that you are stuck on? It seems like you've mostly figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using `path-has-extension?` over `regexp-match`.

Next, provided that the files you are traversing aren't massive, you can use `file->string` to get the contents of the file as a string. From there, you can use `regexp-match*` to get a list of all of the `#>` in the string, and `length` composed with `add1` to get the number you want.<sup>1</sup>

Finally, you can wrap all of this into a for/fold, to get the total value across all files.

Your resulting code will look something like:

```
(define (scrape-directory path)
  (for/fold ([acc 0])
            ([f (in-directory path)] #:when (path-has-extension? f ".faa"))
    (define text (file->string f))
    (define file-total (add1 (length (regexp-match* #rx"#>" text))))
    (+ acc file-total)))
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>If it is a truly massive file, you can also just use a lexer, such as the `parser-tools/lex` library.</sub>